# Woocommerce Ajax cart update when state select field is changed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to update shopping cart via Ajax when user change the shipping state field selector, but with no success. My code is the follow:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ava_cart_refresh_update_qty', 9999 ); 
function ava_cart_refresh_update_qty() { 
    if (is_cart()) { 
        ?> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            var triggerUpdate = function() {
                $('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'select.state_select', function(){ 
                    console.log('test');
                    $("button[name='calc_shipping']").trigger("click");
                 });
            }

            triggerUpdate();

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                triggerUpdate();
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script> 
        <?php 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't requires Ajax. To auto update on change state requires to be a delegated event attached to `<body>` like:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wc_cart_submit_on_state_change');
function wc_cart_submit_on_state_change() {
    if ( is_cart() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var state = '';

        // update cart on delivery location checkbox option
        $(document.body).on( 'change', '#calc_shipping_state', function() {
            if( state !== $(this).val() ) {
                state = $(this).val();
                $('button[name="calc_shipping"]').submit();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: With this code the page is refreshing constantly on an infinite looping even with no user interaction.

Comment: Great to check your demo, I will take a test with storefront theme. Thank you!

Comment: unfortunately did not works even with WC Storefront default theme, it keeps refreshing in loop the cart page. May be it is due to some configuration on shipping and locations?

Comment: @PLazzo Strange as for me it works on 2 different test servers… maybe you can try to replace `.trigger('click');` by `.submit();`

Comment: GREAT GREAT GREAT!!! It works with .sbumit(); THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!

Comment: @PLazzo I have started using `submit()` and I changed to your `.trigger('click');` provided code… so I update now my answer.